# Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element' - Ionic using swiper

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, swiper.js

Code detail swipper customer

```
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-top', {
  pagination: 'swiper-top .swiper-pagination',
  slidesPerView: 1,
  autoplay: 2500,
  spaceBetween: 2,
  loop: true
});
```

Code Controller detail

```
function TestController($scope, TestService) {
    TestService.getTest().$promise.then(function (result) {
    $scope.tests = result;
  }, function(err) {
    $scope.tests = null;
  });
}
```

Code Html view detail

```
<div class="slide-top slide-header" ng-controller="TestController">
  <div class="row" style="padding: 0">
    <div class="row-slide">
      <div class="swiper-container swiper-top" style="height: 170px">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="slide" ng-repeat="test in tests track by $index">
          <div class="swiper-slide" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(http://static.lingo.vn' + '{{test.IMAGE_PATH}}'}" style="background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat">
            <!--<img src="http://static.lingo.vn{{test.IMAGE_PATH}}" width="100%" height="auto">-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when running, error messages:

> Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not
>   of type 'Element'?

Thank you !!!

Comment: Are you solved this error?